# Why is cauchy transform absolutely integrable?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I can't quite see why the following integral should be finite.
Given a compact set $F$, the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ and a compactly supported and integrable function $\phi$ show that

$\int_{F}\int_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{|\phi(\tau)|}{|z-\tau|}dzd\tau<\infty$.

It looks to me that for each fixed $\tau$ for which $\phi(\tau)\neq0$ the contribution of the integral term
$\int_{\mathbb{C}}\frac{|\phi(\tau)|}{|z-\tau|}dz$ is infinite and so if the support of $\phi$ has positive measure the integral should then be infinite. Why is it not so?

Comment: Do $dz$ annd $d\tau$ denote integrals with respect to _area_? If so then yes you're right, this is  wrong..

Comment: I thought so, Thank you